# Assign signal in many processes

Tags: vhdl

I try to learn VHDL language I don't understand a strange thing. This thing refers to the signals from an architecture.

My question is: Why we can't assign bit signal, integer signal, etc in more than one process/ concurrent assign. But I saw, we can assign in more than one process Std_logic_vector signal and Std_logic signal.

Comment: *"But I saw, we can assign in more than one process Std_logic_vector signal and Std_logic signal."* Please show us the code where you think that is correctly used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read through the [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section, and ensure your question follows the guidelines, since that will give you most success getting answers in this forum.

Comment: "It is an error if, after the elaboration of a description, a signal has multiple sources and it is not a resolved signal.", IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations. "The resolution function associated with a resolved signal determines the *resolved value* of the signal as a function of the collection of inputs from its multiple sources.", 4.6 Resolution functions. The resolution function for std_logic or std_logic_vector (named  resolved) is found in the std_logic_1164 package body. Restrictions on multiple drivers can be target device limited and defined by synthesis tools.

Answer (score 1):

> It is an error if, after the elaboration of a description, a signal
>   has multiple sources and it is not a resolved signal.

IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations.

> The resolution function associated with a resolved signal determines
>   the resolved value of the signal as a function of the collection of
>   inputs from its multiple sources.

4.6 Resolution functions.

The resolution function for std_logic or std_logic_vector (named resolved) is found in the std_logic_1164 package body.

Restrictions on multiple drivers can be target device limited and defined by synthesis tools.

<sup>made @user1155120 's comment a community wiki answer</sup>