# implementing external interrupts in Simple As Possible (SAP) computer with FLAGS registers

Tags: vhdl, cpu-architecture

I am currently learning basics computer architecture and I am working on implementing a FLAGS register that handles external interrupts. Supposedly the output of the register is connected to the controller to handle which instruction to execute upon the interrupt. Based on the output signals, the output shows conflicting signals when driving the signals to the controller. I presume this is because of the concurrent processes between the external interrupt driving signals to flag_data(3) interrupt flag and flag_out <= flag_reg process, but I'm not quite sure how I can improve this. My question is, what am I doing wrong here and how can I fix the implementation provided below?

To provide more context, once the interrupt happens at execute cycle (at 50ns) the controller supposedly sets the carry flag to 1 which is supposed to be flag_data(0). Signals are level triggered where controller and datapath operations happen at the falling and rising edges of the clock, respectively. At this part of the computer cycle, the external interrupt only manipulates the MSB and LSB of the flag signals (interrupt and carry flags). Also, Lf pin is used on updating the flag_reg signals while the new flag output is provided at rising edge considering it to only drive new signals during datapath execution (rising edge of the clock).

```
library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    
    entity flags is
        Port ( 
           clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           i : in STD_LOGIC; --interrupt pin
           Lf : in STD_LOGIC; -- update flags register
           flag_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); -- input from ALU
           flag_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0)); -- output to controller
end flags;

architecture Behavioral of flags is
    signal flag_reg : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin

    flag_reg <= flag_in when Lf = '1';

    process(clk, i) is
    begin
        flag_reg(3) <= i;
        if rising_edge(clk) then flag_out <= flag_reg; end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

[image: Output signals for datapath simulation where flag register output is conflicted during external interrupt]

Comment: `flag_reg <= flag_in when Lf = '1';` This concurrent statement is elaborated into a process with drivers for the elements of `flag_reg`.  The unlabeled process has drivers for `flag_reg` as well. One or more drivers in a resolved type have their value determined by resolution.  The resolution table is found in package std_logic_1164 (the package body). The resolution for example of '1' and '0' on two different drivers would be 'X'. The solution is to drive elements of `flag_reg` from only one process.  You can use unresolved std_ulogic_vector and would be notified of a multiple driver error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign signal in many processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269172/assign-signal-in-many-processes)

Comment: Your question doesn't actually contain a question. *I'm not quite sure how I can improve this* isn't a specific programming question nor do you provide a [mcve].  The concurrent signal assignment causes latches in synthesis. Use an intermediary signal for the version from the process and add an else choice to the concurrent conditional signal assignment statement with a waveform that's the intermediary signal (a multiplexer selecting between flag_in and the flag_register intermediary signal). Perhaps from the code shown the concurrent signal assignment should be to flag_out?

Comment: And that wouldn't need a new signal, rather `flag_out <= flag_in when Lf = '1' else flag_reg;` (What is SAP in this context? Your title is mystifying.)